# CSS Animation fadeOut / fadeIn for JS Popup

Tags: javascript, css

I want create an `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` effect for my JS popup window in css.

`fadeIn` works fine but not the `fadeOut` effect, i dont know how i must change my `JS` time, i have tried some things, but if i use both, `fideIn` and `fadeOut` in `CSS`, the Popup just flashing.
But i want an 5 seconds effect for both and with an delay of also 5 seconds to show the popup.

**CSS fadeIn:**

```
.fadeInclass {
  animation: fadeIn ease 5s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease 5s;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn ease 5s;
  -o-animation: fadeIn ease 5s;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn ease 5s;  
}


@keyframes fadeIn{
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

**JS:**

```
var div = document.getElementById("show-popup");    
var showFlag = true;
var myIntv = setInterval(function() {
    if(showFlag){
        div.style.display = 'block'; 
        showFlag = false;
    }
    else{
        div.style.display = 'none';
        showFlag = true;   
   }
}, 5 * 1000);
```

Whats the best way to add the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` effect, with `js` or `CSS animation`?
5 seconds `fadeIn` effect, then stay for 5 seconds and again 5 seconds `fadeOut`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a single animation to achieve all of this.

The first 5 seconds fades in the control, it stays fully visible for 5 seconds, and then fades out for 5 seconds.

```css
.fadeInclass {
  animation: fadeIn ease 15s;
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 50px;
}


@keyframes fadeIn{
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  33% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  66% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fadeInclass"></div>
```

Comment: This works only if i set my JS time to `15 * 1000`, i understand 15 seconds.. but can i start it after 5 seconds the animation?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use CSS transition with opacity:

```
#popup{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease opacity 5s;
}
#popup.fadeInclass{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

And then just add/remove the .fadeInClass to your element in JS to achieve the desired goal:

```
function showPopup(){
  var div = document.getElementById("popup"); 
  div.style.display = 'block'; 
  div.classList.add("fadeInclass");
}

function hidePopup(){
  var div = document.getElementById("popup"); 
  div.classList.remove("fadeInclass");
  setTimeout(function(){
    div.style.display = 'none'; 
  }, 5000);
}
```